# Using a grid wrapper, how would can I make a one side bleed while maintaing the centered content?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Following [this tutorial from Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c13gpBrnGEw&t=693s), I got a grid layout that works nicely with "full-width", "breakouts" and "normal width".

The problem is that I'm trying to make a "one-side-full-width", but the content inside of this new class/wrapper is not following the centered layout.

[Here is a JSFiddle showing the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/gxlpes/2Lmacgz1/37/)

I know that `grid-column: full-width-start / content-end` make the container work like I said, but the content inside of it is being centered using the container as parameter and not the "content-start" and "content-end'.

**How can I maintain this structure while making the text inside of the wrapper centered?**

```
<div class="content-grid">
  <section style='background-color:red' class="half bg-secondary section-padding flow">
    <h2>This section has a different background-color</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam voluptates vitae reiciendis corporis
      molestias aspernatur vero eaque obcaecati neque dolores veritatis repudiandae voluptas consectetur voluptatum
      nobis maiores doloremque, nostrum deleniti!</p>
    <p>Aspernatur, dignissimos. Quaerat corporis, itaque porro dolore ea a placeat molestiae nihil voluptatem veniam
      facere, corrupti in vel, voluptates enim soluta sint dolores? Quaerat laboriosam iusto voluptatem accusantium
      ex alias?</p>
  </section>
  <section class="full-width bg-primary section-padding flow">
    <h2>This section has a different background-color</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam voluptates vitae reiciendis corporis
      molestias aspernatur vero eaque obcaecati neque dolores veritatis repudiandae voluptas consectetur voluptatum
      nobis maiores doloremque, nostrum deleniti!</p>
    <p>Aspernatur, dignissimos. Quaerat corporis, itaque porro dolore ea a placeat molestiae nihil voluptatem veniam
      facere, corrupti in vel, voluptates enim soluta sint dolores? Quaerat laboriosam iusto voluptatem accusantium
      ex alias?</p>
  </section>
  <h2>Back to normal</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto nam at praesentium cumque rem molestias
    earum officia neque nemo sunt laboriosam vero eum optio, saepe dolorem exercitationem quod asperiores iste?</p>
  <p class='breakout call-to-action'>Not sure why, but we could set things up if ever you wanted random text to be
    full-bleed without bothering with a div or anything on the outside of it as well</p>
  <p>Error nulla doloribus ex, eius voluptates saepe, in quae ea nesciunt rem possimus obcaecati consequuntur
    deleniti. Tempore deleniti deserunt harum, distinctio, culpa atque numquam ducimus repellat fugit iusto eveniet
    velit.</p>
  <h3>Images as full-bleed works too</h3>
  <img class='full-width' src="https://unsplash.it/1600/400" alt="">
  <p>Exercitationem dolorum animi at autem tempore omnis, dolorem saepe sint totam architecto, vitae cum doloribus
    illo? Laudantium laboriosam saepe eligendi ipsam corrupti molestias expedita tempora eos minima, facere, eius
    dicta.</p>
  <p>Magnam eius beatae similique officiis quaerat. Natus est dicta temporibus a. Aut mollitia magnam quo. Sequi
    repellendus voluptas quia suscipit autem iste! Accusamus, delectus beatae inventore obcaecati ut totam ab.</p>
  <p>Eligendi ea maiores asperiores sed nobis qui, animi sint? Ratione laboriosam cum quasi repudiandae in,
    necessitatibus veritatis nihil perferendis maiores consequuntur magnam perspiciatis minus est quibusdam, voluptate
    voluptas natus corporis.</p>
  <p>Vero, facilis! Animi quam dolor a sunt, quae placeat perspiciatis quia odio quisquam at tempore dolorem eum
    ratione vel minima eaque repellendus dolores architecto necessitatibus velit reprehenderit amet et rem.</p>
  <p>Quos, animi expedita facere iste soluta accusamus et facilis, temporibus nemo praesentium iusto aliquam voluptas
    magnam pariatur blanditiis optio, corporis laborum quas? Quis libero aperiam est fuga veniam eos tenetur?</p>
  <section class="bg-primary full-width">
    <h3>content</h3>
  </section>
</div>
```

```
.content-grid,
.full-width,
.half {
  --padding-inline: 1rem;
  --content-max-width: 1200px;
  --breakout-max-width: 1500px;

  --breakout-size: calc((var(--breakout-max-width) - var(--content-max-width)) / 2);

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    [full-width-start] minmax(var(--padding-inline), 1fr)
    [breakout-start] minmax(0, var(--breakout-size))
    [content-start] min(100% - (var(--padding-inline) * 2), var(--content-max-width))
    [content-end]
    minmax(0, var(--breakout-size)) [breakout-end]
    minmax(var(--padding-inline), 1fr) [full-width-end];
}

.content-grid > :not(.breakout, .full-width, .half),
.half > :not(.breakout, .full-width, .half),
.full-width > :not(.breakout, .full-width, .half) {
  grid-column: content;
}

.content-grid > .breakout {
  grid-column: breakout;
}

.content-grid > .full-width {
  grid-column: full-width;
}

.content-grid > .half {
  grid-column: full-width-start / content-end;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code ans error as a text, and not a screenshot.